# Div with z-index: 9999 being hidden by iframe with z-index: -1 IE8-

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6

I've got a popup dialogue which is just a `div` that's got `display:none` when not in use.
It works in most cases except for one scenario when another site displayed in an `iframe` manages to be shown on top of the `div`.

As the title says I've tried using `z-index` with no luck. It works in IE9, FF, Chrome and Safari. IE8, IE7 and IE6 all fail.

Any ideas of what could cause this or how it could be fixed would be great. I've been unable to recreate the problem on a small scale which is the reason why I'm unfortunately unable to provide sample code.

The only hunch I have is that it's related to resizing of the content inside the `iframe` but it's a hunch not verified.

Comment: have you tried the `position: relative` fix to the top-most div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricvk turned out to be to place an iframe of the same size on the same coordinates under the div.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell for sure without seeing the code, but I suspect you're seeing [this IE z-index bug](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html)

> In Internet Explorer positioned elements generate a new stacking
>   context, starting with a z-index value of 0. Therefore z-index doesn't
>   work correctly.

The solution is to position (relative) the parent element of the popup and give it a high z-index:

```
<div id="parent" style=" position: relative; z-index: 9999;">
  <div id="popup" style="z-index: 999;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: would that explain why the elements of the document inside the iframe ovrerides the content outside the iframe? The iframe/popup integration (in main document) works with out any issues. It's only for specific content in the iframe that it fails